# iATS Payments scheduled jobs not created

Tags: iats

When I set up the iATS payments extension a few weeks ago, it seemed fairly simple. But then I discovered that recurring payments weren't processing, which led me to realize that not only were scheduled jobs not triggered, but the jobs didn't exist. Shouldn't the extension have created those jobs by default?

I have manually created the iatsrecurringcontributions Job to run daily, and it executed manually just fine.

However, I was unable to manually create the iatsacheftverify Job with the error: "Given API command is not defined."

I wasn't able to find proper documentation on what jobs should be created by default (I found these two in other SE questions that were a few years old). What am I missing? Is there something newer?

CiviCRM 5.39.0, Joomla! 3.10.6, iATS ext 1.7.4

### Update:

On further exploration, I see that the local iATS extension files are at

/home/[user]/www/www/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/iatspayments

which seems off, as all other extensions are at

/home/[user]/www/www/media/civicrm/ext/

The Extension Resource URL setting is "[civicrm.files]/ext/" where [civicrm.files] is "https://[domain]/media/civicrm/". The CiviCRM Resource URL is set to "administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/".

I seem to recall that Joomla hasn't always played well with the URL variables, so I wonder if that is impacting where Civi installed this extension, leading to the inability to find certain resources.

Comment: Looks like something went quite wrong installing the extension. What version of CiviCRM is this on?

Comment: CiviCRM 5.39.0, Joomla! 3.10.6, iATS ext 1.7.4

Comment: Just seeing on the Civi Extensions page that iATS requires a db upgrade. The upgrade fails: 
[Error: Upgrade com.iatspayments.civicrm to revision 1_2_010]
( entity name )

Comment: found this old thread: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues/75, and tried clearing the cache, but that didn't help.

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT I've managed to get the iatsverify job running, and it finds contributions to verify, but it never processes any approvals, pendings, or rejections. They just sit there in Civi as "pending".